# In golang, how to type assert an interface{} to a type specified by a reflect.Type?

Tags: go

For example, I have an `interface{}` named `a`, and I also have an `reflect.Type` called `elemType`. Now, I want to type assert a to `elemType`, but `a.(elemType)` can't be compiled successfully. How to fix it?

Sorry for my confusing expression. My meaning is that I get a type from a function, and I want to type assert an interface{} to this type, but this type is stored in a reflect.Type variable.

What I want to do is similar to the code below:

```
var a interface{}

//do something

func getType() reflect.Type {
    var ret reflect.Type
    //do something
    return ret
}

targetType := getType()
result := a.(targetType)
```

Comment: elemType is not a type, it is a var, that's why that type assertion cannot work. You could do a type assertion to `reflect.Type`, but somehow I doubt that's what you want to do. Show us some code maybe?

Comment: Puh, empty `interface{}` _and_ type assertion to `reflect.Type`! Are you sure you a) must and b) should solve your problem like this? Sometimes reflection is the best way to do things, sometimes the empty interface is helpful, but both are not the most straightforward way to solve problems.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a standard type assertion in Go:

```
v := a.(typeName)
```

Here the compiler can determine the type of the variable `v` at compile time, and make use of that knowledge when compiling any further statements involving the variable.

With your example of using a `refltect.Type` variable in the assertion, it would be impossible to determine the type of `v`, so the code could not be compiled.

If you need to check that a particular interface variable is of a particular type at runtime, you can still do that with the `reflect` package.  For example:

```
// if elemType is a normal type
if reflect.ValueOf(a).Type() == elemType {
    fmt.Println("type matches")
}

// if elemType is an interface, can check if the value implements it
if reflect.ValueOf(a).Type().Implements(elemType) {
    fmt.Println("value implements interface")
}
```

But you will need a concrete type to return back to standard variables.  If you've only got a small selection of possible types, perhaps using a type switch might do what you want.